# How to open routerLink in next column of the row in angular?

Tags: html, angular

I'm creating a dashboard,and created sidebar menu using bootstrap grid.Now I want when I click any sidebar menu's routerLink. my objective is open that link in next column of the row,as usually happens in dashboards/admin panel.
But here in my case,when I click the link it goes to next page.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-2">
<div class="list-group">
     <a routerLink="dashboard" class="list-group-item active"> Dashboard</a>
        <div>
           <a class = "list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" 
                  href="#collapse1">Accessories</a>

          <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse bgColor">
             <div class="list-group">
      <a routerLink ="add-new" class="list-group-item">Add new Accessory</a>
      <a routerLink ="view-accessories" class="list-group-item">View Accessories</a>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
<div class="col">

</div>
</div>


I expect the output that link should be open in next column of row.
but here in my case it goes to next page. how to resove this.[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVyLQ.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

That it usually achieved by having a layout where constant elements (like dashboard) are outside the router outlet. Say, in your AppComponent:

```
<app-navbar></app-navbar>
<app-vertical-nav></app-vertical-nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```